# Referencing type in nested C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, syntax

I'm puzzled by this problem with C++ templates.

I have a class defined below:

```
template <class T>
class DataConsumer
{
public:

    DataConsumer() : processCount(0)
    {}

    ~DataConsumer()
    {}

    // Sub classes override this in order to do their thing
    void preConsume()
    {
        std::cout << "Preconsume called" << std::endl;
        processCount++;
    }

    virtual void consume(const T *dataSource)
    {
        preConsume();
    }

private:

    long long processCount; // The bare bones template keeps track of the number of data frames it has consumed
};
```

The DataConsumer template is expected to take a type DataSource. DataSource is itself a complex type; meaning it is also templated with another parameter:

```
template <class T>
class DataSource
{
public:

    // C-tor and D-tor
    DataSource() : currentFrame(new T)
    {}

    // Note that this is a weak assignment as the data
    // is not copied; the pointers are merely set to the
    // existing frames properties
    DataSource(T& existingFrame) : currentFrame(new T)
    {
        currentFrame->frame = existingFrame.frame;
        currentFrame->meta = existingFrame.meta;
    }

    ~DataSource()
    {}

    // Update function. Specializations expand on this
    void update()
    {}

    // Return a const pointer to something (the data source can be an image frame, textual, binary etc.)
    const T * getCurrentDataFrame() const
    {
        const T * const frame_ptr = currentFrame.get(); // Just return an unmodifiable pointer
        return frame_ptr;
    }

    void echo()
    {
        // Generic data source just prints its current frame
        std::cout << currentFrame->frame << currentFrame->meta << std::endl;
    }

private:

    boost::shared_ptr<T> currentFrame; // The actual data frame object
};
```

My problem is this: I want to query the underlying template parameter of the DataSource object *in* the DataConsumer class. For example, this snippet of code works fine:

```
    virtual void consume(const T *dataSource)
    {
        preConsume();
        std::cout << dataSource->getCurrentDataFrame()->toString() << std::endl; // This WORKS!
    }
```

What I really want is to get is the type returned by getCurrentDataFrame():

```
    virtual void consume(const T *dataSource)
    {
        preConsume();
        INSERT_TYPE_HERE * frame = getCurrentDataFrame();
        std::cout << frame->toString() << std::endl; // How do I do this?
    }
```

Can someone please help me with the syntax required?

Comment: `INSERT_TYPE_HERE * frame = getCurrentDataFrame();` - was that supposed to be `dataSource->getCurrentDataFrame();` as in your "working" example?

Comment: No; this is exactly my question. I want to declare a local variable rather than writing dataSource->getCurrentDataFrame() every time.

Comment: You can declare a typedef inside the DataSource that represent the template parameter type (type traits technics). Or if in C++11 use a `decltype` construct. You can also template the `consume` method and catch the template parameter.

Comment: Jean-Baptiste, this sounds like what I'm trying to do. Can you expand on your comment in an answer, or direct me to resources explaining the type traits technique please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With type traits:

```
template <class T> DataSource {
public:
    typedef T element_type;
};
template <class T> DataConsumer {
public:
    void consume(T *arg) {
      typename T::element_type local_var;
      ...
    }
};
```

With C++11 decltype:

```
template <class T> DataSource {
};
template <class T> DataConsumer {
public:
    void consume(T *arg) {
      decltype(arg->getCurrentDataFrame()) local_var;
      ...
    }
};
```

With template member function:

```
template <class T> DataSource {
};
template <class T> DataConsumer {
public:
    template <class X> void consume(DataSource<X> *arg) {
      X local_var;
      ...
    }
};
```

You can also use C++11 auto if you only want to catch the return of your function call:

```
template <class T> DataSource {
};
template <class T> DataConsumer {
public:
    void consume(T *arg) {
      auto local_var = arg->getCurrentFrame();
      ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Chosen this as the answer as it is the most informative one

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT_TYPE_HERE * frame = getCurrentDataFrame();
```

Maybe use auto?

```
    auto frame = getCurrentDataFrame();
```

The "type_traits" technic is basicallly having public typedefs. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct DataFrame { };

template<typename T>
class DataSource
{
    public:           
       typedef DataFrame<T> frame_type;
       //using frame_type = DataFrame<T>; // c++11
};

template<typename T>
virtual void consume(const T *dataSource) // imagine T is DataSource
{
    preConsume();
    T::frame_type * frame = getCurrentDataFrame();
    std::cout << frame->toString() << std::endl; // How do I do this?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually one creates `typedef` inside template to alias its underlying type and dependent types

```
template <class T>
class DataSource
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type const * pointer_to_const_type;
    // ....  
    // Return a const pointer to something (the data source can be an image frame, textual, binary etc.)
    pointer_to_const_type getCurrentDataFrame() const
    // .....
```

and than in `DataConsumer` code

```
template <class T>
class DataConsumer
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

virtual void consume(const DataSource<T> *dataSource)
{
    preConsume();
    typename DataSource<T>::pointer_to_const_type frame = getCurrentDataFrame();
    std::cout << frame->toString() << std::endl; // How do I do this?
}
```

also if you can use c++11 standrad you can use an `auto` keyword instead of `typename DataSource<T>::pointer_to_const_type` as @Phantom points already.

Comment: also if he can use c++11 he could use `using` instead of `typedef` :)